# Wordpress Form + vTiger CRM Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, vtiger

I'm trying to create a form in wordpress that will send information to vTiger crm and go to a custom registration page.

I have account-form.php loaded in my own plugin -

```
 <form id="quickreg" name="Quick Registration" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/registration/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="publicid" value="86705670b55224a08b5ec544c86f5e93">
        </input>
        <input id="name" type="hidden" name="qname" value="Quick Registration">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" value="" name="qfirstname"  required="true" placeholder="First Name">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" value="" name="lastname"  required="true" placeholder="Last Name">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" value="" name="email"  required="true" placeholder="Email">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" value="" name="phone"  placeholder="Phone Number">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" value="" name="label:Birthdate"  required="true" placeholder="Birthdate">
        </input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Astro Sign</label>
        <select name="label:Astro_Sign" required="true">
            <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
            <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
            <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
            <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
            <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
            <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
            <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
            <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
            <option value="Sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
            <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
            <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
            <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="btn-qreg" type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </input>
    </p>
</form>
<br />
```

and i have my quickform.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btn-qreg").click(function() {

    var url = "http://localhost/mycrm/modules/Webforms/capture.php";
    var sdata =  $("#quickreg").serialize() + "&name=" + $('#name').val() + "&firstname=" + $('#firstname').val();


    alert('1');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : sdata,
        success : function(data) {
        alert('2');
        }
    });

    return false;
}); });
```

The problem is when I send the form with "return false;" I don't get the normal form behavior, when I remove "return false;" I have the normal behavior but I don't have the ajax working at all. I need both of them working.

Comment: Why don't you "send information to vTiger" in the registration page? Also, what is this for `onsubmit="return submitForm();"`?

Comment: It is a vtiger question or an Ajax one?